# How to save copied strings in multiple lines separated by comma in atomic vector in R?

Tags: r, string, vector

I wanted to save large copied string as a atomic vector in R. Copied string look like this:

```
"div_incr, firm_value_1 , firm_value_1_ind , size , size_ind , life_cycle , 
       life_cycle_ind , sa_borrowings_scaled_ta"
```

I wanted to save above string as an atomic vector where every name should appear as an element of vector. I tried this:

```
var <- c("div_incr, firm_value_1 , firm_value_1_ind , size , size_ind , life_cycle , 
       life_cycle_ind , sa_borrowings_scaled_ta")
```

But this save whole string as single element. I wanted to save like this:

```
var <- c("div_incr", "firm_value_1", "firm_value_1_ind" , "size" , "size_ind" , "life_cycle" , 
       "life_cycle_ind" , "sa_borrowings_scaled_ta")
```

I know, I can do this manually, but I want some R style to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to either use `strsplit` to split at `,`

```
v1 <-  strsplit(str1, "\\s*,\\s*")[[1]]
> str(v1)
 chr [1:8] "div_incr" "firm_value_1" "firm_value_1_ind" "size" "size_ind" "life_cycle" "life_cycle_ind" "sa_borrowings_scaled_ta"
```

---

or `scan`

```
v1 <- scan(text = str1, what = "", sep=",", strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
v1 <- v1[nzchar(v1)]
```

-output

```
> v1
[1] "div_incr"                "firm_value_1"            "firm_value_1_ind"        "size"                    "size_ind"               
[6] "life_cycle"              "life_cycle_ind"          "sa_borrowings_scaled_ta"
> str(v1)
 chr [1:8] "div_incr" "firm_value_1" "firm_value_1_ind" "size" "size_ind" "life_cycle" "life_cycle_ind" "sa_borrowings_scaled_ta"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "div_incr, firm_value_1 , firm_value_1_ind , size , size_ind , life_cycle , \n       life_cycle_ind , sa_borrowings_scaled_ta"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
readClipboard() |>
    paste(collapse = "") |>
    stringr::str_replace_all("[\"|\n]", "") |>
    strsplit(",") |>
    unlist() |>
    trimws()
#[1] "div_incr"                "firm_value_1"            "firm_value_1_ind"       
#[4] "size"                    "size_ind"                "life_cycle"             
#[7] "life_cycle_ind"          "sa_borrowings_scaled_ta"
```